# Where can I find the Windows version Galileo firmware v1.0.0

Tags: windows, intel, iot, firmware, intel-galileo

I have registered the Windows Developer Program for IoT and received the Intel Galileo board from Microsoft.

According to the information on the box, there has a pro-production Windows come with this board, so that we can boot into Windows using the Intel Galileo board.  And it also suggested us to find additional information from Intel.

From Intel's web page, it's suggested to upgrade the firmware to latest version in order to get the latest fix and feature.  So, I just upgraded the firmware to v1.0.2 here.

After the upgrade, I can still boot into Windows, but when I attempt to execute the sketch from Visual Studio, it will cause error when accessing the pin using pinMode function.

After debugging the pinMode function, it was found that the error will reported in GpioSetDir:

pinMode(led, OUTPUT); -> _InitializePinIfNeeded(pin); -> _InitializePinIfNeeded(pin); -> _InitializePin(pin); -> Wire.begin(); -> EnableI2C(true); -> GpioSetDir(GPORT1_BIT5, 1);

Error was thrown after checking the return from GpioSetDir, -> ThrowError("Failed to configure I2C_CONTROLLER mux");

I have posted the question in WindowsOnDevices.com, someone has also tried to fallback the firmware to v1.0.0 from Intel, but the Windows cannot be booted after fallback.

So, it seems that Microsoft has made some changes on the firmware in order to make it work.

Does anyone know where I can get the v1.0.0 firmware which has been customized by Microsoft, so that I can fallback the change and continue my testing on Windows Developer Program for IoT.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's version of galileo use a custom made firmware. Updating or flashing the Intel firmware will have you unable to use Windows, so you are stuck like all of us with a linux galileo. 
As soneone told me is possible to have the firmware on the SD you received from microsoft. If u can do an Image from that SD and post it I can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved as MS has announced a new version of Windows which works fine with 1.0.2.

https://connect.microsoft.com/windowsembeddedIoT/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=54159